# Scala, accessing members when the object is initializing

Tags: scala, subclass, base-class

```
class InitializationTest {
  abstract class Base {
    method()
    def method(): Unit
  }

  class Subclass extends Base {
    val obj = new Object
    override def method(): Unit = {
      println(obj) // null
      // How to get the Object here?
    }
  }

  @Test
  def doTest(): Unit = {
    new Subclass()
  }
}
```

As I experimented, the `println(obj)` expression will output `null`.

My question is, if I need to access obj in `method` of `Subclass`. What should I do without change obj from `val` to `var`, or I can't do?

Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing the reason to call `method` in this way, the immediate workaround would be to declare the `val` as `lazy`

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to define `obj` as a `lazy val`.

Another one is using *early definitions*:

```
class Subclass extends {
  val obj = new Object
} with Base {
  override def method(): Unit = {
    println(obj) // not null!
  }
}
```

These solutions (and some others) can be found [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need an early initializer

```
class Subclass extends {
    val obj = new Object 
} with Base {
    override def method(): Unit = { 
        println(obj)
    }
}
```

Your code tells the compiler "run the constructor for Base, then run the constructor for Subclass" leading to a null access for obj.

The code I've written tells the compiler "run the unnamed extension, then run the constructor for Base, then run the constructor for Subclass" since, obj is initialized in the unnamed extension, it is applied first, before Base gets a chance to access it.